# Why can I not comment though I have "comment everywhere" privilege on Meta Ask Patents?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, privileges, per-site-meta

Why can I not add a comment on Meta Ask Patents to, e.g., [Question 47](https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47) although I have the "[comment everywhere](https://patents.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)" privilege (only 1 rep. needed)?

First, I was hesitant to raise this question as I found quite a lot of similar questions asking for help on commenting. It turned out that the reason for these questions often was too low a reputation to comment.

So I first [raised the question](https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191) on the meta site of "Ask Patents" to make sure that it is not a problem with my low reputation. Indeed, I received an answer from a user with over 5000 reps. who could not comment, either. That indicates that it is not a problem with reputation.

Thus I placed this question here because it may be a feature of the stack exchange engine or another policy barring me and some other users from commenting. I might also be a bug :-)

**Details**:

- On (Meta) Ask Patents, the threshold for the "comment everywhere" privilege is set to 1, see the [list of privileges](https://patents.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) of that site.
- The "add comment" link is missing not only on the question but also on answers from other users.
- The "add comment" link appears on my own answer.
- The "edit" link is greyed out and its tooltip says "Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites."
- Screenshot how I see the "question 47" page:
  [image]

Comment: What error do you receive when trying to comment?

Comment: @hjpotter92, no error message appears, the "add comment" link is absent. I will update my questions to reflect this.

Comment: @mehow You linked to the meta privileges page, which is empty (there's no rep on per site Metas, thus no rep-tied privileges). The [main site privileges page](http://patents.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) for Ask Patents claims "comment everywhere" is awarded at 1 rep.

Comment: @mehow You're looking for [this](http://patents.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta)

Comment: youre guys are right

Comment: I see the "add comment" links on Ask Patents (and Meta AP), and I successfully posted a comment on your Meta question there. When did you last try commenting? Perhaps this has been fixed in the couple of days since you posted on Meta AP?

Comment: I was able to reproduce with account having 1 rep. @Yannis you start with 101 rep thus you can't repro. Most likely the meta site *thinks* 50 rep are required, hence not showing "add comment". That's a bug.

Comment: By the way this appears to be specific to Meta Ask Patents, other per-site metas require 50 rep as far as I could see.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd There's a 5K user there claiming he couldn't comment either. http://meta.patents.stackexchange.com/a/194/82

Comment: @Yannis well, with this account (101 rep there) I can comment just fine so guess only users with certain rep range can see the "add comment" link. On the other hand, with the 1 rep account I couldn't comment on any question, so it's not specific to question #47.

Comment: I've got the same issue on stackoverflow

Comment: Can you still reproduce this issue?

Comment: @hichris123 Now I see an "add a comment" link on the question and every answer. However, when I click it, a tooltip says that I need 50 reps to comment. Currently I have 38 at Meta AP. Basically, the behaviour is unchanged: I cannot comment on questions and answers over there.

Comment: @Sklivvz See above ^.

Answer (score 2):

The short, but unsatisfactory, answer is that at the moment it requires 1 rep to comment on main, but 50 rep to comment on meta.

I'm investigating further and will update this answer later.

Comment: Thanks for helping. However, your comment seems inconsistent to what can actually be observed: a) The privileges page for Ask Patents claims "comment everywhere" is awarded at 1 rep. see http://patents.stackexchange.com/help/privileges  b) As mentioned above, there is also a user having +5000 reputations on (Meta) Ask Patents who could not comment, see http://meta.patents.stackexchange.com/questions/191/why-can-i-not-comment-on-question-47/194#194